# How to calculate confidence intervals?

Tags: r, statistics, confidence-interval

To calculate confidence intervals, I used different formulas, and the only possible one that gives me a plausible result is this one.

```
ci.lower <- (2 * n * p + z^2 - z * sqrt(z^2 - 4 * n * p * (1 - p) + 
            4 * (n * p + (z^2 / 4)))) / (2 * (n + z^2))
ci.upper <- (2 * n * p + z^2 + z * sqrt(z^2 - 4 * n * p * (1 - p) + 
            4 * (n * p + (z^2 / 4)))) / (2 * (n + z^2))
```

I thought this was Cole's Agresti method, but when calculating using the library, the result for Cole's Agresti is different. Please tell me which method this formula corresponds to.

Calculate confidence intervals, I used different formulas, and the only possible one that gives me a plausible result is this one.

Comment: Your code looks different from this reference: https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section2/prc241.htm

Comment: yes, the code is different. But it works great for calculating confidence intervals, and I'm trying to figure out exactly what has been changed in the formula and which method corresponds to it

Comment: Just giving a possible answer for why your method is different from the library.  Your implementation doesn't look like the reference.  Perhaps theirs is based on something like the reference.